# Is there a way of applying server SSL certificate in ASP.NET Core 3.1 application endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, nginx, certificate

I have an Nginx configured on my Ubuntu VPS. Certificate works perfectly on front-end endpoints (*.html) but I'm having trouble fetching data from my ASP.NET Core API from any client-side app. For an example trying to fetch data with following python code:

```
import requests
import json
data = {"somevariable" : "someData"}
url='https://myDNS:myPort/myEndpoint'
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

returns a following error message:

> SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'))

My goal is to communicate with ASP.NET endpoints using Nginx generated certificate (HTTPS) from any client. I have tried the following documentations but none of them seemed to solve my problem.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-nginx
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy

Application has SSL enabled and Program.cs looks like following:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    //webBuilder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5001");
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000); //Should listen on https://MyDNS:5000/
                    });
                });
    }
```

I also use HttpsRedirection on the same port in my Startup.cs like following :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //.... rest of configuration
        }
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //...
            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
                options.HttpsPort = 5000;
            });
            //...
      }
```

I would be really thankful for any answer.

Comment: Are you sure nginex configured correctly? what do you see in the browser on the URL https: // MyDNS: 5000? Can you show the nginex configuration for your site? IMO nginex should listen on a port other than 5000 (same as the asp application)

Comment: It shows that https: // MyDNS: 5000 is unsafe. So you say that I should take a closer look into nginx config and find out the certificated ports? Nginx configuration updated in post

Comment: Hi. Can you please check why the certificate validation is failing? You can click on the certificate icon (should be to the left of the address bar on chrome) and see the actual problem. The problem must be (an educated guess) with the certification path, for, your PC probably do not trust the issuer.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Browser cannot even find certificate for MyDNS on specified port. Should I specify port somewhere in nginx.conf ?

Comment: If you request through secure sockets layer https '(https : //MyDNS : port), whatever the port is, the browser will try to negotiate (SSL handshake) with the server to ensure server identity. If it says that the site is unsafe, it must have done the handshake but did not like the certificate. If you can be kind enough to share the actual (if it is public) dns name, I can show you the problem and probably offer a solution. nginx configuration can be another issue here, but first let's get rid of the certificate validation, then can we continue with your web server configuration.

Comment: @OguzOzgul the site is : https://api.vojtechpetrasek.com/ . I realised that the port was not secure in nginx configuration and when I have tried to use 'listen myport ssl' but after that I couldn't run the program on that port.

Comment: Show nginex configuration - it should look like https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins  (in Edit the Configuration)

Comment: server {
    server_name api.vojtechpetrasek.com;

 location / {
    include proxy_params;
   proxy_pass http://unix:/home/VPetras/test/app.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.vojtechpetrasek.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.vojtechpetrasek.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's nginex config problem.
try modify config to:

```
server 
{ 
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name api.vojtechpetrasek.com; 

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:5000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:5000 https://api.vojtechpetrasek.com;
    }

#.... managed by Certbot 
}
```

Your asp.net app should run on http://localhost:5000
(on linux You can test it by "links http://localhost:5000")

good tutorial
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins